# Getting a field value from another layer in the expression builder (dialog)

Tags: qgis, expression

How can I use QGIS 3 expression builder (Expression Dialog window) to get the value of a field that is in another layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_feature()` to search for a feature in the `layer_id` that contains a `value` in the `field_name` and then get your value with `attribute()` in the `other_field_name_which_value_you_need`:

```
attribute(
    get_feature('layer_id',
                'field_name',
                'value'),
'other_field_name_which_value_you_need')
```